# The last owner of a chat room should not be able to be removed

Tags: feature-request, chat

Today, I did this:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19237/chatroom-of-shame

[image]

I changed the room to gallery mode and removed myself as owner, essentially eliminating the ability for anyone to talk in the room.

I propose that the last owner of a chat room should not be able to be removed, ensuring that there is always at least one owner.

Comment: Some people have waaaaaaaaayyy too much time on their hands...

Answer (score 11):

I feel like the proper response to this is "don't do that." Don't moderators still have access to it anyways? If someone really wanted to be in the room and there's no owner, I say it's fair game to whoever wants to claim it on Meta.

Comment: "Doctor, My finger hurts when I touch it like this." "Then don't touch it like that."

Comment: Moderators are global owners of every chat room, so they could readd another owner in any case.

Comment: @MadScientist Moderators are not global owners... They just happen to have privileges that are a superset of owners' privileges.

Answer (score 5):

If mods are global owners, then I suggest a confirmation like "you are the last owner for this room, are you sure you want to leave the room?" or something along those lines should suffice

Comment: I would rather say "you are the only owner of the room." A warning should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be to just eliminate the ability for people to remove themselves as owner.

Comment: I could create a room, and pass its ownership to somebody else; that is perfectly acceptable. The problem is with rooms without any owner. A warning that explains what it is happening should suffice. ("You cannot add yourself back as owner of the room." or "This actions is irreversible." should make anybody careful of what s/he is doing.)