# I removed myself from being a room owner by mistake. Can I undo it?

Tags: support, chat, room-owner

I have changed my access, I was owner of chat room and I gave myself explicit read access so I was automatically removed as the owner.

Is there any rule that you can be a part of only one thing in particular chat room in terms of accessibility? Is there a way I can make myself owner again?

Comment: You can't just magically "undo" any action. I have edited the question to make some sense.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks.. :-(

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154955/the-last-owner-of-a-chat-room-should-not-be-able-to-be-removed

Comment: Not exact like that but still any other solution..??

Answer (score 7):

No, such thing is not possible. Without the Room Owner status, you can't appoint anyone to be room owner, including yourself.

This is like being locked outside your own home, without the key.

Your only option is asking a diamond moderator to give you the ownership back, and for this you can ask in the local Lounge/Tavern, where moderators are usually present.

Last but not least, friendly tip: grant Room Owner access to another user you trust. This way when such mistakes happen, the other Room Owner can simply give you access again.

Comment: Shadow... you may want to put that "Trust" in bold... Room owners can delete each other ownership with no check at all, so it is pretty dangerous to make someone owner of your room. The day after, you may find out now he is the only one.

Comment: @Derpy I might as well put it inside double quotes. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I added you back to room owners.  :)

Comment: Spoiler alert, he wasn't actually an owner until now :D

Comment: No, i am owner in that room and i added him back